# Run SQL scripts in Oracle Developer Days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using `SQL*Plus` in `Oracle Developer Days` via `Virtual Box`. I am not sure how to specify file path to run `sql` scripts. I keep getting the error `unable to open file`.

Can anyone advise please?
Thanks in advance!

```
SQL> @/HOME/ORACLE/LIST.SQL
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/HOME/ORACLE/LIST.SQL"
```

Comment: Have you googled yet "http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=yuIAU_XkEdHarQfnn4G4Ag&gws_rd=cr#q=how+to+run+sql+from+file+in+sqlplus"

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#CJAGIECA. This might help you

Comment: i sure did. Still googling as well.

Comment: @pa1geek thanks. tried both @ and START. Still same error.

Comment: Are you aware that the Linux file system is case **sensitive**? `/HOME/ORACLE/LIST.SQL` is a different file than `/home/oracle/list.sql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, only found out about it awhile ago. Thanks. :) manage to run the scripts now.